# cp error in script

Tags: command-line, bash, scripts

I get the following error when I run the script that follows:

```
cp: cannot stat ls
```

Script contents

```
#!/bin/bash
#make copies of all files in directory
cd /home/don
LIST='ls'
for i in $LIST; do
    ORIG=$i
    DEST=$i.old
    cp $ORIG $DEST
    echo "Copied $i"
done
```

Can someone see the problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well , there is a small error in your script. In the fourth line you meant to execute *ls* so it should not be in single quotes rather it should be wrapped inside the symbol **``**. So your script changes like as follows

```
LIST=`ls`
```

Try updating your script as above.

However, it is advisable to not use `$(ls)` at all, you should prefer shell globbing in the loop header.

```
for i in *; do
```

As like [Mr.David Andersson](https://askubuntu.com/users/23689/david-andersson) commented below that this could be used with a quotes for variable values( **" $i "** ) for the statements following it else it could  make problems with spaces in filenames. You can prevent this by using find combined with process substitution:

```
while read l; do
    i=$(basename "$l")
done < <(find . -name '*' -maxdepth 1)
```

A detailed answer with script and explanation is given below by [Mr.Arronical](https://askubuntu.com/users/320386/arronical). Kindly refer it for better scripting in future.

Comment: Yes, that can be done. To avoid confusing other people who read the script, i avoid the asterisk altogether and use `$( command )` . Instead. This probably should be noted in your answer a possible alternative

Comment: I answered right to the question. He was asking about the problem in this script and I hope I am done with it. Possible alternatives can be many and  the tips to improve the quality of writing the bash script seems to be relevant and I possible try including it now onward.

Comment: @SAGARBHOOSHAN  David properly noted that `for i in *; do` doesn't have a problem with spaces in filenames, not unless you don't quote the `$i` variable (and by that I mean something like `for i in * ; do stat "$i" ; done` ), so please edit your answer.

Comment: 'while read i; do ... "$i"...; done < <(find ...)` have problems with backslash ("\") in filenames, or space at the beginning or end of a filename. Better `while IFS="" read -r i; do ... "$i"...; done < <(find ...)`, but that still can not cope with newlines in filenames. Granted an unusual case, and it can be fixed, but it becomes a bit more complicated.

Comment: `for i in *; do` has no problem with spaces in filenames. Expanding "$i" without quotes has that problem. (See answer by Arronical). The preferred way to iterate over files is `for i in *; ... "$i" ...`. Most other ways either bug out on space, ? or * in filenames, or become unnecessarily complicated.

Answer (score 9):

One of the main errors is that you're trying to use the `ls` command, but the variable LIST only contains the string 'ls'. You can use command substitution with the `$(command)` syntax. I would advise against it in this case, as it's not going to give you information in the format that you can easily use. It is almost always a [mistake to parse the output of `ls`](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs).

In this circumstance you should use shell pattern matching, also known as [globbing](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/glob).

I'd suggest the following method in your script instead:

```
#!/bin/bash
#make copies of all files in directory
for i in /home/don/* ; do
  if [[ -f $i ]]; then
    orig="$i"
    dest="${i}.old"
    cp "$orig" "$dest"
    echo "Copied $i"
  else
    echo "${i} is not a file"
  fi 
done
```

- This uses shell globbing to match all files in the directory. `./*`
  means everything in the current directory (`.`).
- The `if` statement checks whether the match is a file (will fail on
  directories and links), and does your copy sequence if it is.
- I've changed the variable names to be lower case, as system
  environment variables are upper case, so you'll avoid any unwanted name
  clashes.

Comment: I changed $1 to $i in line 5 of your script and it works fine.Thanks

Comment: Just in case filenames have spaces in them, the $i variable should be quoted to prevent word splitting. Otherwise, good job Arronical

Comment: Also, cd is  unnecessarily here, just provide full path, like `./home/don/*`

Comment: Thanks @Serg, I kept the `cd` in there to more closely echo the OPs original script, but agree that using an absolute path is preferable.

Comment: Not requested by the OP, but, with the normal meaning of ".old" one could consider `cp -p` to preserve file attributes. (If not, "old" will be newer than not old.)

Comment: I'd normally use `-a` to preserve everything, though I suppose there's an argument for wanted the modified time on there, to see when the last copy was executed.

Answer (score 2):

#### The 'find' command vesion

Your  script can be done as one-liner `find` command, without the need of parsing `ls` or messing with globs , etc.

Your goal, as far as the question reads, is to make copies of all files in the current directory. For that, the appropriate command would be:

```
find . -maxdepth 1 -mindepth 1 -exec cp {} {}".old" \;
```

What this does is that `find` operates on all files in `.` (current) directory and calls `cp` per each file ( hence `\;` ).  Because `find` is recursive, this we have to limit the depth of search , hence `-maxdepth` flag, and `-mindepth` flag is to avoid listing `.` as one of the search results.

Sample run:

```
$ touch "file one"  "file two"                                                 
$ find . -maxdepth 1 -mindepth 1 -exec cp {} {}".old" \;                       
$ ls -1                                                                        
file one
file one.old
file two
file two.old
$
```

**NOTE**: `cp` will still complain about directories. There's a couple of ways to deal with this.

1) you could filter out only files if that's your goal with `-type f` flag in `find` like

```
find . -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1 -type f -exec cp {} {}".old" \;
```

2) Use `cp -r`  to make copies of directories as well

```
find . -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1 -exec cp -r {} {}".old" \;
```

#### Python one-liner

This is slightly lengthier that `find` one, but still gets the job done and has no issue with special filenames.

```
python -c 'import shutil; import os;[shutil.copyfile(f,f + ".old") for f in os.listdir(".") if os.path.isfile("./" + f)]'
```

Sample run:

```
$ touch "test file 1" "testfile 2"
$ python -c 'import shutil;import os;[shutil.copyfile(f,f + ".old")
> for f in os.listdir(".")
> if os.path.isfile("./" + f)]'
$ ls -1  
test file 1
test file 1.old
testfile 2
testfile 2.old
$
```

To include directories, use `shutil.copytree(source,destination)`

```
python -c 'import shutil; import os;[shutil.copyfile(f,f + ".old") if os.path.isfile("./" + f) else shutil.copytree(f,f + ".old") for f in os.listdir(".")]'
```

Note that this will fail if say `directory_one.old/` already exists

Comment: +1 for alternative methods, will the find version just complain about no `-r` on the `cp` command if it encounters a directory?

Comment: When encountering a directory my system says `cp: omitting directory 'dir1'`. One could add the find option `-type f`. Then the find solution will match the functionality of both the python solution and the bash solution by Arronical in the other answer.

Comment: @Arronical No, the `find` version will still complain about no `-r` in `cp` , so you can add it. Essentially what `-exec` does it calls `sh -c `. (In reality that's exec system call on C program level , but for all practical purpose, think of it as `sh -c` ).

Comment: @DavidAndersson I've updated my answer to include directories into consideration